# Quickest way to index an existing database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, normalization

I just got a table in excel from our existing accounting program including all the products in our company.
I immediately noticed that the fields "HOOFDGROEP" (translates to "Category") and "SUBGROEP" (translates into "Subcategory") do not include primary keys, but string values.
I imported this table into access, but now I want to make 2 seperate tables, "Categories" and "Subcategories". This way I can index the database. I used an SQL query to extract the groups like this :

```
INSERT INTO Hoofdgroepen
SELECT DISTINCT HOOFDGROEP
FROM Artikelen
```

But now how do I quickly replace all the record's 'HOOFDGROEP' fields to its index value without doing it manually or with find/replace?

As an example I want to as quickly as possible create a table called hoofdgroepen like this (achieved by above query):

```
ID  HOOFDGROEP
3   Cat V
4   Contante betalingskorting
5   Diversen
```

out of this :

```
ID  §kop_artikel        A_ inv_ product     HOOFDGROEP   
238 80010077            Chappe              Cat V                                    
239 80010517            Beton per m3        Cat V                                    
240 9799044704539       Betalingskorting    Contante betalingskorting   
241 9799044704537       Viszak klein        Diversen        
242 9799044704538       Viszak middel       Diversen
```

and then make that table into this:

```
ID  §kop_artikel        A_ inv_ product     HOOFDGROEP   
238 80010077            Chappe              3                                    
239 80010517            Beton per m3        3                                    
240 9799044704539       Betalingskorting    4   
241 9799044704537       Viszak klein        5
242 9799044704538       Viszak middel       5
```

Comment: "*I [..] noticed that the fields [..] do not include primary keys, but string values*" - does not make *any* sense. A primary key can be a string value just as well.

Comment: then what I thought I learned about primary keys is wrong, i want to achieve that for example the category "materials" , gets an index :1, so that "materials" doesnt occur thousands of times

Comment: [Read the documentation on indexing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/prevent-duplicate-values-in-a-field-HA010283317.aspx#BM1) and come back if you are still unable to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please post a small data sample and a note on what you would like it to be. It is usually very easy to create new fields / columns in MS Access. I suspect you want something like `SELECT DISTINCT INTO Materials WHERE Mid(SomeField,3,4) = 'Something')`

Comment: Edited the question what the desired outcome would be

Comment: I don't see `SUBGROEP` in your sample data.

Comment: Is your [hoofdgroepen] table *only* going to have those two columns: a numeric [ID] column and a column named [HOOFDGROEP] that contains unique text values?

Comment: I left out some records , this is just an example

Comment: You're confusing indexing with normalization. What you want to do is normalize your database - a good thing. For normalization to work, you need keys (primary key on Hoofdgroep, remote key on artikelen). For keys to perform and to implement uniqueness, you create indexes.

Comment: Please don't just give everything an id. If the table only has to be in Dutch ever, there is no need for an id. The string might as well just be the primary identification.

Comment: It's to speed the table up, and I don't think what langauge it is matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim sSQL As String
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

sSQL = "SELECT t.HOOFDGROEP INTO HOOFDGROUP " & _
"FROM aTable t " & _
"GROUP BY t.HOOFDGROEP;"

db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

sSQL = "ALTER TABLE HOOFDGROUP ADD COLUMN ID AUTOINCREMENT"

db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

sSQL = "SELECT t.ID, t.[§kop_artikel], t.[A_ inv_ product], HOOFDGROUP.ID INTO " & _
"aNewTable " & _
"FROM aTable t INNER JOIN HOOFDGROUP ON t.HOOFDGROEP = HOOFDGROUP.HOOFDGROEP;"

db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Depending on what you want, you may also need:

```
 ALTER TABLE HOOFDGROUP ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID)
```

Comment: what langauge is this? where do I use this?

Comment: When trying to use the sql queries seperatly , everything worked except the last one (not the primary key one) gave me this error : Resultant table not allowed to have more than one AutoNumber field

Comment: CLng(HOOFDGROEP.ID) AS HOOFDGROEPID fixed this, thanks!